# How can I implement the functionality to share OTP via WhatsApp in a C# ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, whatsapp

I am trying to send an OTP through Whatsapp to a customer; the default template "hello_world" is working.

This is my code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestPage()
{  
    try
    {
        var accessToken = "EAAFpO17oG70BOwxpxug******";
        var recipient = "91894******";
        var templateName = "send_otp";

        var facebookApiService = new FacebookApiService();

        var response = await facebookApiService.SendMessageAsync_OTP(accessToken, recipient, templateName, "123456");
 
        ViewBag.Response = response; 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        ViewBag.Error = ex.Message;
    }

    return View();
}
```

This is a test page, on page load I am trying to send a test otp.

SendMessageAsync_OTP function

```
public class Component1
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string sub_type { get; set; }
    public string index { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter1> parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter1
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter1> params1 { get; set; }
}

public async Task<string> SendMessageAsync_OTP(string accessToken, string recipient, string templateName, string otp)
{ 
    var payload = new
    {
        messaging_product = "whatsapp",
        to = recipient,
        type = "template",
        template = new
        {
            name = templateName,
            language = new { code = "en_US" },
        },
        components = new List<Component1>()
        {
    new Component1()
    {
       type = "body",
       parameters = new List<Parameter1>()
       {
          new Parameter1 { type = "text", text = otp },
          new Parameter1
          {
             type = "localizable_params",
             params1 = new List<Parameter1>
             { 
                new Parameter1 { type = "text", text = otp }
             }
        }
    }
   },
    new Component1()
    {
        type = "button",
        sub_type = "url",
        index = "0",
        parameters = new List<Parameter1>()
        {
            new Parameter1 { type = "text", text = otp }
        }
    }
},
    };

    var jsonPayload = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "111925748604876/messages");

    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
    request.Content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return responseContent;
}
```

In `ViewBag.Response` I get this error:

> **OAuthException**: (#132000) Number of parameters does not match the expected number of params
>
> number of localizable_params (0) does not match the expected number of params (1)